# returning only the first value of the largest element

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop

I'm trying to return the largest element in the array. With strings this means the longest string. How do I return only the first instance of the largest element.

My code:

```
function getLongestElement(arr) {
  var max = "";
  var counter = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
      if (arr[i].length > counter) max = arr[i]
      }
  return max; 
}

getLongestElement(['one', 'two', 'three', "thre1"]); // "thre1" not "three".
```

I'm not quite sure whats wrong with this code.  No matter what the largest value is it only returns the last element in the array.  Help?

Comment: You never update `counter`. EVERYTHING is bigger than zero, so if you had the array `["a", "bb", "c"]`, you'd get `"c"` returned.

Comment: `return arr.reduce((p, c) => c.length > p.length ? c : p);`

Answer (score 2):

`counter` is initialized to 0, but you never change its value so the if statement with `arr[i].length > counter` is always true (unless `arr[i].length == 0`). To fix it you need to keep track of the largest element of the array inside the loop:

```
// I renamed counter to maxLength for readability
function getLongestElement(arr) {
  var max;
  var maxLength = -1;
    for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
      if (arr[i].length > maxLength){
        maxLength = arr[i].length;
        max = i;
      }
    }
  return arr[max]; 
}
```

Comment: Should be `return arr[max]`.

Answer (score 1):

First, good alghoritm should make no assumptions. That means your `max` shouldn't start from "", but using first array's element. You also don't edit your `counter` value, that's your main problem. But it is redundant and you can write this function without `counter`.

```
function getLongestElement(arr) {
  if (arr.length < 1) return /* Some Exception */;
  var max = arr[0];
    for (var i = 1; i < arr.length; i++) {
      if (arr[i].length > max.length) max = arr[i];
    }
  return max; 
}
```

Comment: A string can never be shorter than `""`, so starting from `""` is not really assuming anything.

Comment: Yeah, maybe I was too strict. The only situation would be an empty array. I mean that you wouldn't see difference between an empty array or array with only empty strings. But that may not be a problem, as you said.

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to update `counter`

```js
function getLongestElement(arr) {
  var max = "";
  var counter = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
      if (arr[i].length > counter) {
        max = arr[i];
        counter = max.length;
        }
      }
  return max; 
}

console.log(getLongestElement(['one', 'two', 'three', "thre1"])); // "thre1" not "three".
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for a pragmatic solution, I'd suggest lodash's [_.maxBy](https://lodash.com/docs/4.16.4#maxBy):

```
_.maxBy(['one', 'two', 'three', "thre1"], function(str) {
   return str.length;
})
```

If you're looking for a theoretical solution for the sake of learning,

```
function getLongestElement(arr) {
  var max;
  var counter = 0;

  for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
    if (arr[i].length > counter) max = arr[i]
    counter = Math.max(arr[i].length, counter)
  }

  return max; 
}
```

The key point here is to make sure you're updating the `counter` variable to whatever the currently longest length is.

Comment: `arr[i].length > counter` will never be true, because you set `counter` to `arr[i].length` on the previous line.

Comment: @Barmar I believe I set `counter` to whatever is higher: `counter` or `arr[i].length` (using `Math.max`).

Comment: But you're setting it *before* you test the length of the current element. So if the current element is longer than `counter`, you'll set `counter` to its length, then you test whether it's longer than `counter` again.

Comment: Switch the order of those statements and it should work.

Comment: @Barmar, ah good catch, guess I'm running out of coffee... Thanks.

Comment: I think using `Math.max()` here is the wrong way, though. Since you're already testing whether the current element is longer than `counter`, you can simply set `counter` inside the `if` block, rather than calling a function.